# MediaWiki: Calling Template, ParserFunctions condition depending on External data values

Tags: mysql, templates, if-statement, mediawiki

I'm trying to display data from MySQL DB in a table in my MediaWiki page. The data are fetched using External data extension functions #get_db_data and #for_external_table, which works fine. However, I would like to do two more things:

- use the fetched value as a template name: when value in DB is x, then insert Template:X (or {{X}})
- use (another) fetched value in a condition using ParserFunctions extension. Specifically, a number is returned. If the number is less than 100, display it in brackets, otherwise display nothing.

Here is the code so far:

```
{{#get_db_data:
db=pravidla
|from=alch
|order by=nazev
|data=nazev=nazev,prima=prima,primaproc=prima_proc,sekunda=sekunda,sekundaproc=sekunda_proc,dominanta=dominanta
}}

{| class="wikitable sortable" style="border: solid 1px black"
|+ Tabulka přísad
|''Přísada''
|''Prima''
|''Sekunda''
|''Dominanta'' {{#for_external_table:<nowiki/>
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{nazev}}}
{{!}} {{{prima}}} ({{{primaproc}}} %)
{{!}} {{{sekunda}}} ({{{sekundaproc}}} %)
{{!}} {{{dominanta}}} }}
|}
```

The values in prima, sekunda and dominanta variables should be replaced by a template with the same name. Neither `{{{{{prima}}}}}` nor `{{Lcb}}{{Lcb}}{{{prima}}}{{Rcb}}{{Rcb}}` (where Lcb={ and Rcb=}) do work.

The bracket with the value in the middle two cells should be displayed only in the value is less than 100 (percent), so something like `{{#ifeq: {{{primaproc}}} | 100 | | ({{{primaproc}}} %) }}` should be in order, but I've had no luck despite trying.

Thank you for reading this, and any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve both issues by replacing the ExternalData extension function `#for_external_table` with `#display_external_table`. The latter passes the retrieved data as variables to a template; the same code works when placed in a separate `Template:Table row` page. So the solution looks like this:

Original page, displaying the table:

```
{{#get_db_data:
db=pravidla
|from=alch
|order by=nazev
|data=nazev=nazev,prima=prima,primaproc=prima_proc,sekunda=sekunda,sekundaproc=sekunda_proc,dominanta=dominanta
}}

{| class="wikitable sortable" style="border: solid 1px black"
|+ Tabulka přísad
|''Přísada''
|''Prima''
|''Sekunda''
|''Dominanta'' 
{{#display_external_table:
template=Table row
|data=nazev=nazev,prima=prima,primaproc=primaproc,sekunda=sekunda,sekundaproc=sekundaproc,dominanta=dominanta}}
|}
```

Newly created `Template:Table row` page:

```
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{nazev}}}
{{!}} {{ {{{prima}}} }} {{#ifeq: {{{primaproc}}} | 100 |  | ({{{primaproc}}} %) }}
{{!}} {{ {{{sekunda}}} }} {{#ifeq: {{{sekundaproc}}} | 100 |  | ({{{sekundaproc}}} %) }}
{{!}} {{ {{{dominanta}}} }}
```

Both using the prima, sekunda and dominanta values to call a template with the same name and conditional diplay of percents in the brackets work like a charm now.